# How to empty my clipBoard after App.getClipboard()

Tags: automation, sikuli

For example I copy paste text from a textfield with:

```
type('c', KeyModifier.CTRL)
fieldEntry = App.getClipboard()
```

Now `fieldEntry` is my value that is stored in the textfield.

Now the next textField is empty. 
I use `Key.TAB` to go to the next textField. 
But if I use the `App.getClipboard()` again, I get the value from the previeus textField.

Does anyone know how I can clear my clipboard after I did `App.getClipboard()`?

Edit:

I did create the code below that does the trick. 
But I was wondering if it could be done a bit more simple...

```
from java.awt import Toolkit
from java.awt.datatransfer import StringSelection, Clipboard

def clearClipboardPC():
    toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
    clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard()
    clipboard.setContents(StringSelection(''), None)
```

Comment: We have the same functionality for clearing clipboard. Don't familiar with more clearer way.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of few ways to handle this issue:

**Simulate hitting <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> button**

*Example Usage*: `type(Key.PRINTSCREEN)`

Saving the screenshot to your clipboard doesn't actually cleans it but it can be used as a hack in your case as it will result in empty string when you run `App.getCliboard()` command.

**Clear clipboard using command line**

You can execute qa command line command that will clean the clipboard for your.

*Example usage*: `run("cmd /C echo off | clip")`